# Проходя по списку создавать объект внутри другого

Tags: c#

Вот код:

```cs
class Node
{
    static List<string> list = new List<string>(){"первый","второй","третий","четвертый"};

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Node Node { get; set; }

    static void Load()
    {
        foreach (var @var in list)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Что разместить в цикле `foreach`, что бы при запуске метода `Load` создался бы объект типа `Node` с именем первый, внутри которого был бы объект типа `Node` с именем второй, внутри которого был бы объект типа `Node` с именем третий, внутри которого был бы объект типа `Node` с именем четвертый?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень хромает вопрос: вы куда собрались ваши узлы загружать; непонятно, зачем вам `List` вместо массива; одно св-во с прописной буквы, другое – со строчной, а переменная (`VAR`) вообще капсом; хорошие отступы... Ну да ладно:

```
public class Node
{
    static readonly string[] names = new[] { ... };

    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public Node? Child { get; set; }

    public static Node Load()
    {
        // checks skipped

        var curNode = new Node();
        var rootNode = curNode;

        for (var i = 0; i < names.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            var name = names[i];

            curNode.Name = name;
            curNode.Child = new Node();

            curNode = curNode.Child;
        }

        curNode.Name = names[^1];

        return rootNode;
    }
}
```

<sup>*Примечание*: Вариант рабочий, но можно доработать. Я старался не выходить за рамки модели вопроса.</sup>

Comment: потеряли `curNode = curNode.Child`?

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, исправил